# How to get Date, Month and Year into Millisecond in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi am Trying to convert year, month date into Millisecond how to do please help me to do this,

Bellow Is my Code that i have try.

```
let date:String = "2018-08-04T07:34:15.287Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

var dateFromString = Date()
if let aString = dateFormatter.date(from: date) {
    dateFromString = aString
}

let timeInMiliseconds:Int = Int(TimeInterval(dateFromString.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))

return timeInMiliseconds
```

But I Alway Got DateTime Into Millisecond.
when I am trying to get the only date into millisecond please help I need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `date` defined? and where is `DateTime`?

Comment: Now I have update code date is String "2018-08-04T07:34:15.287Z"

Comment: @AVIRALSINGH If you have the date string "2018-08-04T07:34:15.287Z", what is your expected output?

Comment: You need to convert the string to date first before converting it back to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift - Convert a String to a Date and then to a String in a different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826282/swift-convert-a-string-to-a-date-and-then-to-a-string-in-a-different-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dateFormat is not match with date. Try below code:

```
let date:String = "2018-08-04T07:34:15.287Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let dateToConvert = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let finalDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateToConvert!)

var dateFromString = Date()
if let aString = dateFormatter.date(from: finalDate) {
    dateFromString = aString
}

let timeInMiliseconds:Int = Int(TimeInterval(dateFromString.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
```

> You will get 1533321000000 in timeInMiliseconds

You can check time [here](https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-date)

Comment: Thanks for your Reply I am trying to get only year, month and date and convert it into millisecond that's why i am using this dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: That is not how it works, you need to match the input string. You can not just leave the out part of the format you do not want.

Comment: @AVIRALSINGH Great that worked for you. Could you please accept and upvote answer? It will helps other developers to identify correct answer.